Only 1st image of my site page/post get index rest doesn't why? how to solve it?
My WordPress site posts and page images don't get indexed fully. Google indexes only a single image from a page or post and mostly it's the featured image that gets indexed rest don't. When I created an image gallery for a page, the gallery's 1st image got indexed but the rest didn't. I have added the image sitemap generated through a plugin but it still doesn't work.

It sounds like its a new site.  A new site is not trusted by Google.  It can take weeks to several months for indexing to work.
In the mean time, you need to make sure that you fix any errors in css, html, visualization etc.  Try posting it to Bing and Yandex.  They are stricter and give better feedback - fix everything they say is wrong.
You can also find other websites that will test your site for free (Free, while the site is small), such as Ahrefs.

There are actually two sitemap I added, one works for the blog post & pages another is for images. Should I keep these two or remove one and keep only one?
